# How to load a specific view property from an xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an xib file in which I have a view.
I made a custom view of mine as its file owner in the interface builder.

I have a subview as an outlet for a view in the xib.

On creating the view object isn't loading the subview outlet from the xib.

Is specifying a file as the owner in the IB sufficient ?
Or I will have to load the xib in initWithFrame of my View as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On creating the view it will create all the subviews from the XIB. It is sufficient to specify the file owner in interface builder.

Comment: until and unless I add this in initWithFrame.

NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BOAGetPasswordPopoverView" owner:self options:nil];
        _viewForPopover =  [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];

Nothing appears!

Comment: InitWithFrame does not use the xib. You should use `loadNibNamed` instead.

Comment: My View is a normal UIView subclass. only one of its subviews I am loading from an xib.